# wxPython change the appearance of the UI

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython

I would like to know, if it is possible to change the colors of my ComboBox.

[I would like to go from white of scrollbar to black](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HbyH4.png)

Here is the code of my ComboBox :

```
    self.language_int = wx.ComboBox(self.box, value="Français", choices=self.languages_names, pos=wx.Point(307, 3), style=wx.BORDER_NONE)
    self.language_int.SetSize(wx.Size(80, 25))
    self.language_int.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(77, 77, 77))
    self.language_int.SetOwnBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(77, 77, 77))
    self.language_int.SetForegroundColour(wx.Colour(255, 255, 255))
    self.language_int.SetOwnForegroundColour(wx.Colour(255, 255, 255))
```

Thanks

Comment: Look at `wx.ComboCtrl` which allows customisation of a number of things including background and foreground colours.

Comment: Do you mean you want to change the color of the main combobox background itself, or the color of the scrollbar that pops up when dropping-down the combobox selections? Unfortunately, I do not believe there is a way to change the color of the scrollbar itself, since wxpython just wraps native widgets. So unless the native widget supports such customization, you're SOL.